# Why is drawing good lines in Unity so hard?

Tags: unity

With the new Renderer Pipelines, the OnPostRender-callback is gone, which means GL.Lines is gone.

LineRenderer looks terrible (aliases really badly, and scales with distance from camera).

How do I draw UI lines (similar to the editor "grid", solid color, preferably with controllable width)?

Comment: We can't speculate about "why" the Unity development team chose to implement the rendering systems the way they did. Can we rephrase your question to "how" to achieve a specific line effect? For instance, if you want to render an anti-aliased grid like in your example, we have [existing Q&A on how to solve that specific problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141916/39518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL.Lines are not gone, if using the Scriptable Render Pipeline you can use your GL methods in this event:
[RenderPipeline.beginCameraRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Rendering.RenderPipeline-beginCameraRendering.html)

```
void Start(){
  RenderPipeline.beginCameraRendering = OnPostProcess(yourCamera);
}

void OnPostProcess(Camera camera){
  OnLineRender(Material mat, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, Color color);
}

public void OnLineRender(Material mat, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, Color color)
{
   RenderPipeline.beginCameraRendering = OnPostProcess(yourCamera)
   GL.PushMatrix();
   GL.LoadProjectionMatrix(Camera.main.projectionMatrix);
   GL.modelview = Camera.main.worldToCameraMatrix;

   mat.SetPass(0);

   GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
   GL.Color(color);
   GL.Vertex3(startPos.x, startPos.y, startPos.z);
   GL.Vertex3(endPos.x, endPos.y, endPos.z);
   GL.End();

   GL.PopMatrix();
}
```