# How can I add a visual grid in the game state?

Tags: unity

Much like Unity's built in grid feature used by the scene editor, what is the most efficient way to implement a similar grid into my actual gamestate?

I know unity has the Grid/Tilemap components, but this is mostly an aesthetic task, and I'm not sure if that is the best route.

Thinking about pulling the trigger on the Vectrosity asset. I am curious if there is a better alternative or if I should script something custom?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean creating something like graph paper. With or without Vectrosity, I think you'll be creating/managing the positions of the lines yourself. I don't think there's a strong difference at that point between instantiating VectorLines (Vectrosity) or LineRenderers. If you're on a budget, you could do without it. That said, I do like Vectrosity and use it in every project where I need to draw lines - I haven't created a LineRenderer in years. Weighing the pros/cons is up to you.

Comment: Presumably you've reviewed [previous Q&A about rendering grids](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/92391/39518), including [Unity-specific applications](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141916/39518). What have you tried so far based on this research? Are you stuck on any particular step, or are the results you're getting differing from what you want in any specific way?

Comment: @ChrisMills-Price Graph paper is the perfect description. I ended up getting my desired result with both Vectrosity and LineRenderer. However, Vectrosity is much more convenient in other aspects.

Comment: @DMGregory I wasn't having rendering problems at distance, or anything like the previous Q&A. I was making extremely silly layering errors, for an embarrassing amount of time.